# Having different providers for the same InjectionToken at the route level

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a component that I would like used in two seperate routes, and provide different services for each route - but I'm unsure how to do this. I want to avoid putting logic in the component to decide which service to use.

```js
class MyPage {
    constructor(service: MyServiceInterface)
}
```

Routes

```js
routes = [
  { path: 'one', component: MyPage }, 
  { path: 'two', component: MyPage }
]
```

And then in the module - I want to provide a different service for `MyServiceInterface` for each of those routes

```js
providers: [
   { provide: MyServiceInterface, useClass: PageOneService }, 
   { provide: MyServiceInterface, useClass: PageTwoService }
]
```

Comment: you can use `data` attribute for your problem, there is nopossibility to affect providers iif the route is not a lazy loaded module

Comment: also you can render HostComponetn with some provision logic depending on the data to isolate that logi

Comment: You can simply create "wrapper" components that would be providers of the aforementioned services and both have your `MyPage` component in the template as the only element. Then you can use those components in routing, meaning each route will have different providers. Remember that your component will traverse up the component tree and look for the first possible provider, so it will override the services injected in the module.

Comment: Thanks everyone - @TotallyNewb I had considered this but I wasn't too keen on the boiler plate, but it's a viable options. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrei said in the comments to the question, there is no way to associate providers with a route. In a case such as yours, when you have two routes that are associated with the same component, the component can know which route was used to instantiate it but only *after* its constructor gets injected with everything.

Basically you have to change your strategy, instead of relying on injected services, you should use the `data` or `resolve` properties of the route.

- `data` is used for static data
- `resolve` invokes a guard which can fetch dynamic data.

One way to do it in your case is to use two different guards (`PageOneGuard`, `PageTwoGuard`), which depend on the appropriate service (`PageOneService`, `PageTwoService`) and at the end produce a value that the component can use.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information - are you saying I can use resolve to  essentially fetch the appropriate service?

Comment: You *could* have the guard resolve the service and pass the service itself into the component, but that is going "against the grain" in Angular. A guard should use the service to get whatever data it requires from it, and pass *that* along to the component.